# Homebrew update error that local changes would be overwritten

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I'm very new to homebrew and git.

I've done changes to `httpd24.rb` formula which is in `homebrew/apache` tap.
(Just added the `--enable-so` configuration argument in the existing formula file)

Now when trying to `brew update` I'm getting this:

```
$ brew update
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    httpd24.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/apache
Already up-to-date.
```

Also got this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Library/Formula/httpd24.rb

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

How can I save the changes to formula and be able to keep homebrew updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Commit you changes `git add Library/Formula/httpd24.rb && git commit -m "This is your commit message"`.

When you run `brew update` it's work similar to [git pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) command. If you have non-committed changes you cannot update local repository.

Comment: Thanx, Anton, but it didn't work - still the same error

Comment: Kstati, mojet eto byt' iz-za togo, chto eto formula ne iz defoltnogo repozitoriya, a iz tap-repo (`homebrew/apache/httpd24`)? Do I miss anything?

Comment: @Andrew Ты добавил и закоммитил файл httpd24.rb и у тебя всьо тажеш ошыбка? `Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: httpd24.rb`

Comment: да, абсолютно то же выдает

Comment: Страно, если ты выполниш `git status -s` и тебе выдаст `http24.rb` файлы то ты так его и не закомител. Ладно тут у многих такая же проблема была [1](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/35487#issuecomment-68668926), [2](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/11448) и [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133587/brew-update-not-working-after-mac-10-9/20138806#20138806)

Comment: Cпасибо, Антон! Я наконец разобрался: `git add /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-apache/httpd24.rb && git commit -m "commit msg"` решила мою проблему. Как я и подозревал проблема в пути к файлу httpd24.rb из-за того, что формула не из дефолтного репо. Я не знал как проверить успешность коммита, что и помогло мне найти мою ошибку. Так что засчитываю ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cd $(brew --repository)
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Source: [Common Issues with Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Common-Issues.md).

Comment: Doesn't work. I've also tried : `cd $(brew --repository)/Library && git clean -fd` - No luck, still the same message (((

Answer (score 0):

To fix Homebrew issues, run these commands:

```
git --git-dir $(brew --repository)/.git reset origin/master --hard
git --git-dir $(brew --repository)/.git clean -fd
```

For Git issues, see:

- [How do I resolve git saying “Commit your changes or stash them before you can merge”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15745045/55075)